# Statics not working with any of my projects after attempting to deploy

Tags: css, django, linux, ubuntu, deployment

I was following for this deployment and at the last step my html will pull up but not any of my CSS styling.  The weird part of all this is now none of the projects on my desktop will show their CSS either. So it did not only effect my portfolio but seems "my computer".
any ideas?
this is the error I get when I inspect it

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRjhi.png)

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5502/projects/templates/%7B%%20static%20'css/styles.css'%20%%7D' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

```
Set Up Server
You can use something like Linode or Digital Ocean to follow these instruction.

Step 1: Create a linode 

Step 2: Use terminal or any ssh client to login with root and run:
ssh root@IP
apt update && apt upgrade -y

Step 3: Set hostname for server. I used test-server. You can use whatever you want.
hostnamectl set-hostname test-server

Step 4: Connect host ip and hostname
run nano /etc/hosts and add your server ip, click tab and then your hostname (from step 3)

Step 5: Install some dependencies
run sudo apt install python-pip virtualenv ufw

Step 6: Create a limited user and give sudo privlidges

run adduser USERNAME 
then run adduser USERNAME sudo
logout as root by typing exit and log in with your username: ssh username@IP

Step 7: Set up some firewall rules and enable
sudo ufw default allow outgoing
sudo ufw default deny incoming
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow 8000
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw status (check to ensure its up and running)

Step 8: Setup ssh keys on your local computer
run ssh-keygen -b 4096
leave defaults
run ssh-copy-id username@IP to push them to your server
optional: If you have multiple ssh key pairs then run ssh-add ~/.ssh/{name of ssh key}

Step 9:Remove root login and password auth
run sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Set permit root login to no and uncomment passwordauthentication and set it to no

Step 10: Reboot the server
run sudo reboot

Deploy Django Project to Server
Step 11: Change to your virtualenv
run virtualenv vevn -p python3
run source venv/bin/activate
You should now see something like (venv) on your terminal line

Step 12: Transfer Django project from local computer to server
run scp -r {local path to project folder} username@IP:~/

Step 13: Update settings.py. Navigate to settings.py in your project folder
Set Debug=False
Update Allowed_Hosts =['Add Your IP or Domain Name']
Add static root with the following command STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ‘static') to the settings file
Save and exit

Step 14: Back out to the directory that has manage.py
Run python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: Could you please post the related html file where you include the css as well as the settings.py. After collectstatic do you see the static files in the desired location?

Comment: I'll be honest im not really sure what the 'collectstatic' actually does or did. I know before deploying and following the steps I already had a 'static' folder inside my django project if that matters.

Comment: See this for management of static files in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/